# Install gdal on Redhat 4.4.7-1

Tags: python, installation, redhat, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to install GDAL for python on a Redhat 4.4.7-1 system. I have successfully installed Python (2.7.13) and Anaconda (4.3.1), but I am struggling with the supporting libraries GDAL needs to run. Whenever I open python and attempt `>>> import osgeo` I get the following error

```
>>> import osgeo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In this example, the problem is the libjpeg.so.8 file, but this has happened with a number of libraries. However, with each previous error, I was able to find the missing library and install it, so far I have installed 7 .rpm files in order to solve this problem, and every time a different missing library comes up.

HOWEVER, with this most recent error, I have hit a wall. From what I can tell, this missing library requires an updated version of glibc - I currently have version 2.12, and the library I need requires 2.14. I cannot figure out how to upgrade this!

I am running this as root, but I still cannot seem to upgrade the library. It should also be noted that I do not have a network connection on this machine: I am using putty and ftp to send .whl and .rpm files to install the python and Linux libraries. Any ideas?